# Add website using BibDesk in LaTeX

Tags: texshop, bibdesk

I want to add a website in my research using BibDesk. In LaTeX I tried to add using URL, webpage and misc.

First, I don't know what is the difference between URL, webpage and misc?
Second, when I tried to run the LaTeX code the reference for the website became empty, I don't know why. Can you help me please how to add website?

Pictures: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYjxf.png),[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhX1d.png),[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nu1E.png)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What bibliography style are you using?

Comment: URL: Uniform Resource Locator: unique address on where to find any form of resource, e.g. an image or video. Webpage: any site that contains information and is structured into a form, e.g. homepage of TX.sx. Misc: any type of source, that can't be labeled book, research paper, newspaper article, video, etc. For example a self-written note, you have taken during your research can be quoted as "misc".

Answer (score 1):

### How to add websites as a reference in BibDesk:

1. Start BibDesk.
2. Create new bibliography or update existing one.
3. Click on the green '+'-symbol. A window pops up.
4. Select resource type `webpage` in drop down menu.
5. Enter all relevant data into the fields, e.g. author, address of webpage, date and time of last access, etc. Usually you find these in the imprint.
6. Add citation key, so you can later cite your source in LaTeX.
7. Click on "Add" and you're done. Just add your `.bib`-file to your LaTeX project.

See also BibDesk Tutorial here: https://de.scribd.com/doc/19256352/BibDesk-Tutorial.

Comment: Is `webpage` superior to `URL`?

Comment: @EricAuld I don't think so. I'd reckon `webpage` is treated internally as `URL`, since an `URL` is the address to a webpage containing information.